# How do I wildcard a rule with SECONDEXPANSION in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
# Docker Chain
src_files:=$(shell find src/ -name '*.py')
image_tags=$(shell find dkr/ -name '$(PROJECT).*.dockerfile' | xargs -n 1 basename -s '.dockerfile')

dkr/%.dockerfile: $(src_files)
  docker build . -f $@ -t $*

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(PROJECT).base: dkr/$$@.dockerfile

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(PROJECT).foo: $(PROJECT).base | dkr/$$@.dockerfile

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(PROJECT).bar: $(PROJECT).base | dkr/$$@.dockerfile

publish-%:
  $(MAKE) $*
  ./scripts/$@.sh $(RESOURCE_PREFIX) $* $(REGION)

publish:
  $(foreach tag, $(image_tags), $(MAKE) publish-$(tag))
```

I would like to write the above as:

```
# Docker Chain
src_files:=$(shell find src/ -name '*.py')
image_tags=$(shell find dkr/ -name '$(PROJECT).*.dockerfile' | xargs -n 1 basename -s '.dockerfile')

dkr/%.dockerfile: $(src_files)
  docker build . -f $@ -t $*

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(PROJECT).base: dkr/$$@.dockerfile

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(PROJECT).%: $(PROJECT).base | dkr/$$@.dockerfile

publish-%:
  $(MAKE) $*
  ./scripts/$@.sh $(RESOURCE_PREFIX) $* $(REGION)

publish:
  $(foreach tag, $(image_tags), $(MAKE) publish-$(tag))
```

However, the wildcarding in the rule (via '%') does not work.  I suppose I have misunderstood rule substitution, and am guessing it is due to the `SECONEXPANSION`.

But, my `make` intuition is telling me this should work, and it should be good.

How would I perform substitution in this scenario?

Comment: _does not work_ is not the best possible description of your problem. Can you elaborate? And maybe explain what you are trying to do? Plus: why did you double `SECONDEXPANSION:`?

Comment: Please note that `.SECONDEXPANSION` does not pertain exclusively to the rule following it but _to all rules_ in the makefile from this point on!

Comment: @Vroomfondel thanks for clarifying that -- I did not know.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet imho, it is ok for a question asker to not know everything in the subject matter they are asking about.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I can get debug output.  But from your reaction, it does sound like it should work, so I might have gotten into some kind of edge case for other reasons.

Comment: I'm unclear on the purpose of the first makefile in this question.  Are you saying that that one yields the behavior you want, but the second one not?  In that case, what is the actual behavioral difference you observe?

Comment: In any case, secondary expansion is allowed for pattern rules, and [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) discusses the details.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In the first, I have two rules that I'd like to collapse into 1 via wildcard technique.  However, make fails with "rule to make ... not found" errors.  I am overruling some imported rules related to the word 'publish' from a different makefile, so I suspect the problem is some kind of edge-case related to how make overrules previously defined rules since you are all confused what I am asking and why it isn't working (as am I).  So I probably need to rule that out.  I'll be able to provide a minimal example of the problem when I figure it out.

Comment: @JohnBollinger let it be clear: I am confused as to why it isn't working **and** what I am asking now that I've seen you all's reaction.  It should just work, so my current hypothesis is that I've defined a  `publish-%:` somewhere else, and make at that version doesn't allow imported wildcard rules to be re-defined.  But I won't be able to check for a while.  When I figure it out, I'll modify the question to reflect what I found.

Comment: @Chris I am not expecting you to fully understand the matter, I am just asking what behavior you expect and what different behavior you get. And please add this to your question, not to comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the code above, not "elsewhere". Also, your application of `.SECONDEXPANSION` is correct; the problem is not there.  It is here:

You can have a dependency specification in a makefile, without any recipe to it, like in your first example:

`$(PROJECT).foo: $(PROJECT).base | dkr/$$@.dockerfile`

But, if you try to have such a dependency (without a recipe), with a pattern (`%`), you can't (Make uses such a thing for something else).  To have a "pattern rule", you must supply a recipe.  If you don't really have a recipe, then supply the dummy recipe, which is a semicolon after the dependency line.

So

`$(PROJECT).%: $(PROJECT).base | dkr/$$@.dockerfile ;`

and that will solve your problem.

By the way, I don't see why you need those "order prerequisites" (after the `|`).  They are used to prevent the target from rebuilding solely because the prerequisite is newer.  Since these targets do not have a recipe, there is no point in having order prerequisites.  So just do

`$(PROJECT).%: $(PROJECT).base dkr/$$@.dockerfile ;`

Comment: awesome -- thank you!  That is not an answer I would have found -- NP Complete 'find the house key in the kudzu` stuff. I enforce the order pre-requisite because of reasons that would be out of scope.

Comment: @Chris - yea, this happens to me all the time, it looks like the bug is in "the cloud" somewhere, and I go on a wild goose chase to find it, only to realize it was in front of me staring me in the face